# Error syscall : Function not implemented

Tags: operating-system, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm trying to add new (dummy) system call to linux kernel.

1) I added the system call code under linux-source/kernel/myfile.c and updated the Makefile accordingly.

2) Updated syscall.h, unistd.h and entry.S files to reflect the new system call (pedagogictime(int flag,struct timeval *time))

Then compiled the kernel and installed and rebooted the image.

When I run: `cat /proc/kallsyms | grep "pedag"`, this is the output I'm getting

0000000000000000 T sys_pedagogictime
0000000000000000 d event_exit__pedagogictime
0000000000000000 d event_enter__pedagogictime
0000000000000000 d __syscall_meta_*pedagogictime
0000000000000000 d types*_pedagogictime
0000000000000000 d args__pedagogictime
0000000000000000 t trace_init_flags_enter__pedagogictime
0000000000000000 t trace_init_flags_exit__pedagogictime
0000000000000000 t __event_exit__pedagogictime
0000000000000000 t __event_enter__pedagogictime
0000000000000000 t __p_syscall_meta__pedagogictime
0000000000000000 t __initcall_trace_init_flags_exit__pedagogictimeearly
0000000000000000 t __initcall_trace_init_flags_enter__pedagogictimeearly

which means the system call is registered correctly.

In my user space program, I'm writing:

```
#define __NR_pedagogictime 1326 //1326 is my system call number
struct timeval *now = (struct timeval *)malloc(sizeof(struct timeval));

    long ret = syscall(__NR_pedagogictime,0,now);
    if(ret)
            perror("syscall ");
```

But I'm getting the error:

"syscall : Function not implemented"

I would really appreciate any help about this. Thanks.

Edit:

Btw, the assembly code for the syscall() looks like this (if it helps):

```
    movl    $6, %esi
    movl    $1326, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    syscall
    cltq
```

Comment: Why did you choose 1326 as the syscall number?

Comment: Because the last system call in the file natty-source/arch/ia64/include/asm/unistd.h has the number 1325, so I incremented mine by one.

Comment: I doubt you have ia64, you are probably on x86_64 which is quite different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've chosen the wrong syscall number. Take a look at how the kernel checks the syscall number limits [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S?v=2.6.38#L496). For example (x86, 32bit):

```
496 ENTRY(system_call)
497         RING0_INT_FRAME                 # can't unwind into user space anyway
498         pushl_cfi %eax                  # save orig_eax
499         SAVE_ALL
500         GET_THREAD_INFO(%ebp)
501                                         # system call tracing in operation / emulation
502         testl $_TIF_WORK_SYSCALL_ENTRY,TI_flags(%ebp)
503         jnz syscall_trace_entry
504         cmpl $(nr_syscalls), %eax
505         jae syscall_badsys
506 syscall_call:
507         call *sys_call_table(,%eax,4)
508         movl %eax,PT_EAX(%esp)          # store the return value
```

So, you can see that this code compares `%eax` (syscall number) and `nr_syscalls` (sys_call_table size). Above or equal leads to `syscall_badsys`.

You'll need to modify the [arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h?v=2.6.38) header too.

Comment: Yes, that was my thought as well.  I suspect this is x86_64 though from the address lengths and the pattern of assembly used.  There used to be a warning in unistd_64.h about not having gaps in the syscall table; there's a huge re-organization in linux 3.something but I expect gaps are still problematic, and 1326 seems suspiciously high.

Comment: Okay. I got what you're saying. Since the system calls start at 1024 in that file: "natty-source/arch/ia64/include/asm/unistd.h", mine was getting the number 1326. When I changed it to 303, it started working. Thanks very much. But if I simply use the symbolic constant __NR_pedagogictime (as defined in unistd.h as 1326 and unistd_64.h as 303) in my program, it is not able to resolve the symbol. Any reason for this?

Comment: @ChandanApsangi, you probably are using the system's `/usr/include` with the constants filched from the distribution's kernel, not your doctored version. Just `#define` it in your code, so you don't mess up your system.